# Jtds No suitable driver maven tomcat run

Tags: maven, jndi, jtds, maven-tomcat-plugin

Am having problems with this small issue:

Have added dependency to my `pom` like this

```
  ....

  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

.. have added Maven dependencies to my `war` application `build path`

my context.xml looks like :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <Context reloadable="true">
  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDS" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource"
        url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/testdb"
        username="sa" password=""/>     
</Context>
```

...

Still when I execute `mvn tomcat:run` . I get this

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class ''   
for connect URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/testdb'
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
    at     

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining a datasource using JNDI then the driver has to be ["available to both Tomcat internal classes and to your web application"](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources).

So if you only add the driver jar to your war, Tomcat won't be able to find the driver classes.

You can [add the jar to the plugin dependencies](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-50).

Comment: :) .. I just opened the provided link and replaced `driverClass` with  `driverClassName` in my `context.xml` and everything worked .. Thanks for the link :) ..could you plz edit the anwser with this comment so i can mark off

Comment: Sounds like it was a different issue. But it seems odd that it works without the jar being available on the Tomcat classpath.

Comment: correct it will work if the driver is available in the war. which is not a good idea as normally your jdbc driver must be in $CATALINA_HOME/lib if you create this resource at the tomcat level rather than only for your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

and have a look http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html (see how derby dependency is declared)